# Why prefer start + (end - start) / 2 over (start + end) / 2 when calculating the middle of an array?

Tags: c, algorithm

I've seen programmers use the formula

```
mid = start + (end - start) / 2
```

instead of using the simpler formula

```
mid = (start + end) / 2
```

for finding the middle element in the array or list.

Why do they use the former one?

Comment: Wild guess: `(start + end)` might overflow, while `(end - start)` cannot.

Comment: because latter does not work when `start` and `end` are pointer.

Comment: [Extra, Extra — Read All About It: Almost Every Binary Search and Mergesort is Broken](https://research.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html)

Comment: `start + (end - start) / 2` also carries semantic meaning: `(end - start)` is the length, so this says: `start + half the length`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler why anyone would use a *signed* integer as array index is beyond me. I normally use `size_t` for them these days… if you find a case where that’s incorrect, do tell, but I think it works for both char arrays, pointer arrays, and arrays of structs.

Comment: @mirabilos unfortunately, that's just not the type of an array index. native c array indices are signed and of type ptrdiff_t

Comment: @SteveCox hrm, ok. But `size_t` is usually the same as `ptrdiff_t`, just unsigned (making it easier to handle) and more portable (available on many more platforms, especially older ones).

Comment: @mirabilos you can like, size_t better, but `a[-2]` is a valid C expression indexing into an array. this isn't really a question of preference. C array indexing is signed, and an unsigned type is not sufficient for the task.

Comment: @SteveCox `a[-2]` is not a valid index into an array defined as `a[]`, only if `char b[]; char *a = b + 2;` or somesuch, yes. But wrapping around *is* defined for unsigned types, so it would work at least for char types, but probably for others too…

Comment: some other duplicates [Binary search using iterators, why do we use “(end - begin)/2”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38560566/995714), [Overflow issues when implementing math formulas](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10882368/995714). Btw this should be explained in every questions about binary search

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Doesn't this question have the best answers and the most votes? If so, the other questions should probably be closed as a dup of this one. The age of the posts are irrelevant.

Comment: Can we also do mid= (start)/2+(end)/2 ?

Answer (score 229):

There are three reasons.

First of all, `start + (end - start) / 2` works even if you are using pointers, as long as `end - start` doesn't overflow<sup>1</sup>.

```
int *start = ..., *end = ...;
int *mid = start + (end - start) / 2; // works as expected
int *mid = (start + end) / 2;         // type error, won't compile
```

Second of all, `start + (end - start) / 2` won't overflow if `start` and `end` are large positive numbers.  With signed operands, overflow is undefined:

```
int start = 0x7ffffffe, end = 0x7fffffff;
int mid = start + (end - start) / 2; // works as expected
int mid = (start + end) / 2;         // overflow... undefined
```

(Note that `end - start` may overflow, but only if `start < 0` or `end < 0`.)

Or with unsigned arithmetic, overflow is defined but gives you the wrong answer.  However, for unsigned operands, `start + (end - start) / 2` will never overflow as long as `end >= start`.

```
unsigned start = 0xfffffffeu, end = 0xffffffffu;
unsigned mid = start + (end - start) / 2; // works as expected
unsigned mid = (start + end) / 2;         // mid = 0x7ffffffe
```

Finally, you often want to round towards the `start` element.

```
int start = -3, end = 0;
int mid = start + (end - start) / 2; // -2, closer to start
int mid = (start + end) / 2;         // -1, surprise!
```

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> According to the C standard, if the result of pointer subtraction is not representable as a `ptrdiff_t`, then the behavior is undefined.  However, in practice, this requires allocating a `char` array using at least half the entire address space.

Comment: result of `(end - start)` in the `signed int` case is undefined when it overflows.

Comment: Can you prove that `end-start` wont overflow? AFAIK if you take a negative `start` it should be possible to make it overflow. Sure, most of the times when you compute the average you know that values are `>= 0` ...

Comment: @Bakuriu: It's impossible to prove something which is not true.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Then why do you state so in your answer? You should clarify that you are excluding negative `start` values from your observation, even though in some circumstances they are perfectly valid.

Comment: It's of particular interest in C, since pointer subtraction (per the standard) is broken by design. Implementations are permitted to create arrays so big that `end - start` is undefined, because object sizes are unsigned whereas pointer differences are signed. So `end - start` "works even using pointers", provided you also somehow keep the size of the array below `PTRDIFF_MAX`. To be fair to the standard, that's not much of an obstruction on most architectures since that's half the size of the memory map.

Comment: @Bakuriu: By the way, there is an "edit" button on the post you can use to suggest changes (or make them yourself) if you think I've missed something, or something is unclear.  I'm only human, and this post has been seen by over two thousand pairs of eyeballs.  The kind of comment, "You should clarify..." really rubs me the wrong way.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Two's-complement implementations often define pointer subtraction in such a way that if `p2>=p1`, then `(size_t)(p2-p1)` will always yield the correct difference, whether or not the result could be represented in a `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: @SteveJessop Completely true, but you might want to also mention that you can only run into this issue with char arrays. arrays  of larger elements (on implementations with larger elements) never have this issue whatsoever.

Comment: @LittleAlien where did you get 2 from? The midpoint of [0,-3) is -1.5. The `(start + end) / 2` method rounds zero, which means that it rounds up or down depending on sign, giving -1.  If you test with positive numbers this may surprise you.  It doesn't have translation invariance, for one thing.

Comment: @Steve Cox The issue is not limited to arrays. Consider pointer arithmetic and `double *x = calloc(SIZE_MAX, sizeof *x);`.  Some platforms support allocations exceeding `SIZE_MAX`.  `SIZE_MAX` is the limit of the index, not the allocation size limit.

Comment: @chux: You say that some platforms support this.  Can you name a such platform?  I am skeptical.

Comment: Example: Allocations greater than `SIZE_MAX` were accomplished with `calloc()` with DOS [huge memroy model](http://users.pja.edu.pl/~jms/qnx/help/watcom/compiler16/wmodels.html#16BitDataModels).  This is compliant C behavior.  Certainly not as common a flat memory models today.  Not so difficult to write code that handles both.

Answer (score 22):

We can take a simple example to demonstrate this fact. Suppose in a certain **large** array, we are trying to find the midpoint of the range `[1000, INT_MAX]`. Now, `INT_MAX` is the largest value the `int` data type can store. Even if `1` is added to this, the final value will become negative.

Also, `start = 1000` and `end = INT_MAX`.

Using the formula: `(start + end)/2`,

the mid-point will be

> `(1000 + INT_MAX)/2` = `-(INT_MAX+999)/2`, which is **negative** and **may give segmentation fault** if we try to index using this value.

But, using the formula, `(start + (end-start)/2)`, we get:

> `(1000 + (INT_MAX-1000)/2)` = `(1000 + INT_MAX/2 - 500)` = `(INT_MAX/2 + 500)` **which will not overflow**.

Comment: If you add 1 to `INT_MAX`, the result will not be negative, but undefined.

Comment: @celtschk Theoretically, yes. Practically it will wrap-around a lot of the times going from `INT_MAX` to `-INT_MAX`. It's a bad habit to rely upon that though.

Answer (score 19):

To add to what others have already said, the first one explains its meaning clearer to those less mathematically minded:

```
mid = start + (end - start) / 2
```

reads as:

> mid equals start plus half of the length.

whereas:

```
mid = (start + end) / 2
```

reads as:

> mid equals half of start plus end

Which does not seem as clear as the first, at least when expressed like that.

as Kos pointed out it can also read:

> mid equals the average of start and end

Which is clearer but still not, at least in my opinion, as clear as the first.

Comment: I see your point, but this really is a stretch. If you see "e - s" and think "length" then you almost surely see "(s+e)/2" and think "average" or "mid."

Comment: @djechlin Programmers are poor at math. They are busy doing their work. They have no time to attend the math classes.

Answer (score 1):

start + (end-start) / 2 can avoid possible overflow, for example start = 2^20 and end = 2^30